# I would like to build a Ubuntu-Server-based word-processing kiosk

Tags: 16.04, server, kiosk, word-processor

There has been many tutorials on the Internet on how to make Ubuntu-based Chrome kiosks. But none has been done on how to make a word-processing kiosk.

Can you folks please tell me how I could turn a Ubuntu Server 16.04 into a word-processing kiosk ? I would like it to :
- automatically connect me without asking any password
- automatically launch nothing but a word-processor (focuswriter would be my choice, as it is fullscreen, multitab and customizable)
- when I quit the program (or with a keyboard shortcut), the whole PC halts
- allow me to plug flash drives (this kiosk would not connect to the Internet, but act like a typewriter of sorts)

I hope you will find an answer to my question. It's been days that I desperately try to build a word-processing kiosk, but to no avail. Thank you for your answers

Comment: Is it a requirement to start with Ubuntu *Server*? (I see no reason why this wouldn't be feasible, but I'm asking in case it relates to any additional requirements you haven't mentioned yet.) For example, would it also be acceptable to start from an [Ubuntu minimal system](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD), or something else?

Comment: Well, why not. It's just that many tutos advises this distro as the most lightweight solution. But as I've had some problems trying to make it work, any solution might be acceptable.

In fact, I only want it to have one program running, automatic user connexion and... that's pretty much it, in fact.

According to you, how could I customize this mini.iso to be as I want it to be ? I'm listening to your advices

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using 14.04.  I used the base info from https://thepcspy.com/read/building-a-kiosk-computer-ubuntu-1404-chrome/ and changed the Chrome installation process to another program.  You would just need to install the word processor you want and invoke it instead of Chrome.  The one difference is that when you close the word processor it will restart in about 1-3 seconds.

I have mine to the point where I can create the build back to an .iso, use unetbootin to create a bootable USB, boot from the USB and the entire system loads into memeory and the USB can be removed to be used on another machine.  Reboot the physical machine and nothing is left on it except finger prints!

EDIT - I am still looking for a good process using 16.04 as well.

Comment: EDIT EDIT - Just found an updated version of the one for 14.04 at https://dej.in.ua/ubuntu-server-16-04-kiosk-mode/ and am going to test it out.